# Counting how many times a substring occurs in a string

Tags: assembly, substring, counter, x86-16, dos

The university has asked me to write code in x86 assembler that counts how many times a substring is contained in a string. For example, how many times does the string "QWWQQWWQQW" contain the substring "QQ", and the counting code must be in a subroutine.

I know that you can find out if a substring is contained in a string with `repe cmpsb`, but how do you do a counter?

```
data segment
msg1    DB  "Enter string: $"
msg2    DB  0Ah, 0Dh, "Enter substring to find: $"
msg3    DB  0Ah, 0Dh, "Yes!$"
msg4    DB  0Ah, 0Dh, "No such substring$"
 
str1ml  DB  200
str1l   DB  '$'
str1    DB  200 dup('$')
 
str2ml  DB  200
str2l   DB  '$'
str2    DB  200 dup('$')
data ends
code segment
assume cs:code, ds:data
start:
    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax
    mov es,ax
    xor ax,ax
 
    lea dx, msg1    
    call    strout
 
    lea dx, str1ml  ;input string str1

    call    strin
 
    lea dx, msg2    
    call    strout
 
    lea dx, str2ml  ;input string str1

    call    strin
 
    xor cx, cx
    mov cl, str1l   
    sub cl, str2l
    inc cl
    cld         
    lea di, str2    ;in di - the string to be found
    lea si, str1    ;in si - the string in which we are looking for
    xor ax, ax
    call mainp
 
 
quit:
    mov     ah, 4ch     
    int 21h
 
 
;*****************Procedures***********************
 
;*************************************************
strin   proc
    mov ah, 0Ah
    int 21h
    ret
strin   endp
;*************************************************
strout  proc
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h
    ret
strout  endp
;*************************************************
mainp proc
all_string:         
    
    push    cx
    push    di
    push    si
    mov bx, si
    mov cl, str2l
    repe cmpsb
    je  _eq
    jne _neq
_eq:
    lea dx, msg3    
    call    strout
    jmp quit
_neq:
    pop si
    pop di
    pop cx
    inc si
loop    all_string
lea dx, msg4
call    strout
jmp quit    
mainp endp
code ends
end start
```

Comment: The simple approach is to go through the string and check each position. Write the algorithm in high level or pseudocode first.

Comment: Another approach is to load AL with the first byte of `str2` and use `REPNE SCASB`. When found (ZF=1), compare the remaining bytes of `str2` with `REPE CMPSB`.

Comment: Your question is how to do a counter?  If so, find some storage, initialize to 0, add 1 when appropriate.

Comment: @ErikEidt I think in this case there's still plenty of registers to choose from.

Comment: Why are your line feeds before your carriage returns?

Comment: @puppydrum64, yes, registers are storage, would be a good choice for a counter.

Comment: For short substrings, especially 2-byte ones like `QQ`, you can get a big speedup with SSE2 `pcmpeqw`.  There might be something to gain from SSE4.2 `pcmpistrm` for more general substring searching, maybe giving you a mask of candidate start positions.  See https://www.strchr.com/strcmp_and_strlen_using_sse_4.2 about using it for `strstr`, which find the *first* match.

Comment: @PeterCordes Not sure but this looks like 16-bit 8086 code so I doubt that's an option.

Comment: @puppydrum64: It's 16-bit code, but nobody said it had to be backwards-compatible with 8086.  You can't use AVX instructions in real mode, but you can use SSE if you enable it.  But yeah, many people writing 16-bit code are doing it for retrocomputing reasons, which is a big part of why I only commented instead of taking the time to make an answer about it.

Comment: @PeterCordes Fair enough, I've only really used 16-bit code so I don't really understand the concept. So "real mode" is always in 16-bit mode regardless of the CPU?

Comment: @puppydrum64: Yeah, https://wiki.osdev.org/Real_Mode means the PE bit in CR0 is cleared, so `mov ds, ax` or whatever updates DS.base directly instead of using the value to index the GDT.  All x86 CPUs support real mode, and in fact the initial power-on state is real mode.  (Actually unreal mode, CS.base is much higher than 0xFFFF << 4 on 386 and later.)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> str1ml  DB  200
> str1l   DB  '$'
> str1    DB  200 dup('$')
>
> str2ml  DB  200
> str2l   DB  '$'
> str2    DB  200 dup('$')
> ```

Much better to write the *str1l* and *str2l* fields as 0.

Your *mainp* procedure stops on the first positive find. Instead of stopping, now increment a counter and continue the loop.
At the conclusion of the *all_string* loop you currently display the 'not found' message. The new code will have to make displaying this message depending on the value in the new counter.

Next fix will help you on your way, although there's still room for improving this. eg. Will "WWQQQW" count as **1** find or as **2** finds?
And what about displaying the actual number of finds instead of having to gaze at the debugger's output?

```
mainp proc
    xor  bx, bx     ; Counter=0
all_string:         
    push cx
    push di
    push si
    mov  cl, str2l  ; CH=0
    repe cmpsb
    jne  _neq
    inc  bx         ; Counter++
_neq:
    pop  si
    pop  di
    pop  cx
    inc  si
    loop all_string

    lea  dx, msg4     ; 'Not found'
    test bx, bx
    jz   _None
    lea  dx, msg3     ; 'Yes'  (Count is in BX)
_None:
    call strout
    ret   
mainp endp
```